# Assets Manager got File Not Found on Android 5.1

Tags: android

i am writing function that extract zip file i placed in assets folder of apk. The function run well on android 4.4 and android 8.0. But it return error "File Not Found" on android 5.1. My zip file place in assets folder have size over 1GB.

Below is my code of extracting zip:

```
@Override
    protected Long doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        String filename = "apk.zip";
        try {
            String[] listAssets = bb.list("");
            int countProgress = 0;
            for(String s : listAssets){
                if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(filename)){
                    filename = s;
                }
            }
            ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(bb.open(filename));
            BufferedOutputStream dest = null;
            long inputFileSize = getFileSize(filename);
            while (true) {
                ZipEntry entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
                if (entry == null) {
                    zipInputStream.close();
                    mThread = null;
                    break;
                }
                File file = new File(new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(extractdir)).append(entry.getName()).toString());
                if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
                    BufferedOutputStream dest2;
                    try {
                        byte[] data = new byte[8192];
                        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        long stepIncrease = inputFileSize/100;
                        long countStep = 0;
                        dest2 = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOut, 8192);
                        while (true) {
                            if(countStep == stepIncrease) {
                                countProgress++;
                                publishProgress(countProgress);
                                countStep = 0;
                            }
                            int count = zipInputStream.read(data, 0, 8192);
                            if (count == -1) {
                                break;
                            }
                            countStep++;
                            dest2.write(data, 0, count);
                        }
                        dest2.flush();
                        dest2.close();
                        dest = dest2;
                    } catch (Exception e2) {
                        e2.printStackTrace();
                        dest2 = dest;
                    }
                } else if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.mkdirs();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e22) {
           e22.printStackTrace();
        }
        return per;
    }
```

Comment: it looks like the way you extract the filename is somehow broken, your loop seems to not ever assign a new value to filename

Comment: What is `bb` ??

Comment: @greenapps bb is AssetManager (AssetManager bb = getAssets();)

Comment: @StarterPack it broken when i init ZipInputStream, bb.open(filename) can't find that file.

Comment: the problem is that your filename is invalid "apk.zip" is not enough to locate the file you want

Comment: @StarterPack So why it run well in android 4.4 and android 8.0? I can't find another way to get path of file inside assets.

Comment: have you tried debugging to check if your file is in listAssets?

Comment: @StarterPack yes, i already do it. You can see String[] listAssets, it have apk.zip in this list. But don't know why it still got File Not Found Exception